# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined - hoping for a lesson

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

This has been asked many times before, but I'm a novice an very keen to learn so I was hoping someone could take the time to explain this to me. I also haven't been able to work out the solution to this particular error using the currently available answers...

The image gallery that should be displayed under the Image Gallery title is not showing and the error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (scripts.js:1604)
at Function.each (jquery.js:2)
at a.fn.init.each (jquery.js:2)
at markScrollToTargets (scripts.js:1602)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (scripts.js:1552)
at i (jquery.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
at Function.ready (jquery.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js:2)
```

Could someone tell me how to fix this? And, why it happened?

I believe this is the relevant code:

```
function markScrollToTargets () {

        var scrollToSelector = '#';
        var $aTags = $('nav a');    // get all level anchor tags
        var url = window.location.href;
        var urlSplitArray = url.split(scrollToSelector);
        url = urlSplitArray[0];
        var $target;

        $aTags.each(function (index) {
            var $this = $(this);
            var splitArray = $this.attr('href').split(scrollToSelector);
            var thisURL = splitArray[0];
            var thisTargetClass = splitArray[1];

            if (typeof thisTargetClass != "undefined") {    // check if link has a scrollto selector
                if (thisTargetClass != "") {    // check if link has scrollto selector but no actual target class (like just #-link)
                    if (thisURL != "") {    // if link has url before scrollto selector
                        if (thisURL == url) {   // only consider if the link url is the same as current url
                            $("." + thisTargetClass).addClass('scroll-to-target').addClass('scroll-to-target-class-' + thisTargetClass);
                        }
                    } else {
                        $("." + thisTargetClass).addClass('scroll-to-target').addClass('scroll-to-target-class-' + thisTargetClass);
                    }
                }
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: Would be able to show your code? Without it it's nearly impossible to answer this question.

Comment: Make sure that the value you are calling `.split` on is not `undefined`. You are either not passing the correct value, or if the value is only sometimes `undefined`, you need to guard against that and decide what you want to do in case it is `undefined`.

Comment: The code you think contains your error. I would imagine it is somewhere you are trying to to use the split method.

Comment: Seems like not all `nav a` elements have an `href` attribute. What do you want to do with the ones that don't?

Comment: Code added to post

Comment: @FelixKling - If nav a elements dont have a href value, shouldn't they just be ignored? I don't know why this issue has arisen.

Comment: Most likely. It's your code and your decision :)

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling. Don't suppose you could tell me how to alter the code in the question to stop this error occurring by ignoring nav a elements that don't have a href value?

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling. Between yourself and Tipsy, I've got there. Awesome! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to call `.split()` on something that doesn't exist (is undefined). If you run this snippet to debug:

```
$('nav a').each(function (index) {
    var $this = $(this);
    console.log(index, $this, $this.attr('href'));
    var splitArray = $this.attr('href').split('-');
});
```

You will get `8 [a, context: a, selector: ""] undefined` for the 9th element. You should check if the anchor has a href before trying to split.

Comment: Thanks for these responses. I'm afraid I don't know how to debug, so not sure what to do with that answer or how to use it to fix my problem -- I have very little js experience.

Comment: Okay then. In the code you pasted, replace `var $aTags = $('nav a');` with `var $aTags = 
 $('nav a[href]')`, and it should work.

Comment: Amazing -- Thanks so much @Tipsy. Just to clarify (trying to learn!) by changing 'nav a' to 'nav a[href]' that means it is only handling nav a elements that have a href value?

Comment: Yes. jQuery uses CSS selectors (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors), you can save yourself a lot of trouble by using the correct selector.